# Mysql count the frequency of the frequency of ocurrences

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following issue for which I didn't find an answer (yet!).

I have this table:

```
Chile
Chile
Chile
Argentina
Argentina
Peru
Peru
Bolivia
```

And I want to know how many countries have n ocurrences in my table:

```
ocurrences howMany
1             1
2             2
3             1
```

I have one country once (Bolivia), two countries twice (Argentina and Peru) and once country three times (Chile).

I've tried some things, but they didn't work (it's like a count(count+groupBy), sort of thing).

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: *I've tried some things* can you post any one of them

Answer (score 3):

Use a subquery.

```
SELECT occurrences, COUNT(*) AS number_of_countries
FROM (
    SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS occurrences
    FROM table
    GROUP BY country
) AS s
GROUP BY occurrences
```